# How can I defuse the stench of my Carrion Golem?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, constructs

So. I'm a shady wizard. I want to make a [carrion golem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-carrion/), but I'm afraid the stench will be disruptive to myself and the other PCs in the party. Is there any way to disable that stench and/or cover it up so it's not always on, or remove it entirely?

Comment: Is your game by-the-books (i.e. are you looking for things to negate the effects of the ability specifically) or is it more fiction-first (i.e. are you looking for things to make it not smell bad).

Comment: Id prefer a by-the-books answer. But short of a legitimate way to do it. DM is a little lax on the rules.

Comment: Are you specifically looking at removing the mechanical difficulty presented by the Stench, or the roleplay 'why do we have this stinky thing running around with us'?

Comment: [+5 Air Freshener of Pineness](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0526.html) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ignore it.**

A [Carrion Golem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-carrion/)'s Foul Stench ability is a form of the general [Stench](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Stench-Ex-), which says (in part):

> Creatures that successfully save cannot be affected by the same creature’s stench for 24 hours.

You can effectively "take 20" on your fort save in the first 2 minutes of the day. Then, since you've saved against the creature's Stench, you're immune until the next day.

If your only concern is "myself and my party members", just ignore it: assume you wake up every day, have a few rounds of being sickened, and then get used to the smell for the day.

Alternatively, get a few [Necklaces of Adaptation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necklace-of-adaptation/), and become

> immune to all harmful vapors and gases (such as cloudkill and stinking cloud effects, as well as inhaled poisons) and [able to] to breathe, even underwater or in a vacuum.

Note: this GM would let you put a necklace on the golem to contain its stench, but YMMV on that one.

Answer (score 1):

That ability is one of which isn't removed on the carrion golem variants and would require some house ruling to work, or creating a new type of golem without the stench ability (see the rules about [creating and modifying constructs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs#TOC-Pricing-a-New-Construct)), which also requires some *GM fiat* to be allowed.

You can temporarily solve the problem with alchemical items though.

The [Houndbane Dust](http://archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Houndbane%20dust) (75 gp) can remove the sense of smell for 3d6 minutes if you fail a Fortitude check. Which means you could remove your sense of smell before a battle, but wouldn't help during everyday adventuring.

While you can willingly fail [saving throws against magical effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throws), [non-magical effects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Saving-Throws) have no ruling saying that you could do that. There is [evidence](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q30u?What-can-be-done-through-a-Force-Effect#30) that some of the rules in the magic chapter should apply to all kind of effects, but there is also [evidence](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2npb2?Can-a-player-willingly-fail-a-saving-throw#15) that you still would have to get a save against extraordinary effects regardless of your willingness to fail the check.

So the GM would probably have to house rule a decision on that. Regardless of his decision, you don't become immune to the effect if you pass the check, and all the character would have to do is to leave and enter the area again.

If you want the effect to last longer, you could first apply a [Rhinarium Paste](http://archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Rhinarium%20paste) (75 gp) to gain the scent ability, increasing the duration to 24 hours instead of 3d6 minutes.

[Doctor Masks](http://archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Doctor%27s%20mask) (50 gp) can be used to help against the stench's saving throw as well.

Comment: (So far as I'm aware a creature can typically willingly forego a saving throw *only* against a spell (and, by extension, a spell-like and supernatural ability) and some other rare exceptions—among which houndbane dust does seem to number. However, I understand that being able to forego *any* saving throw—even if that's silly, like against, for example, disease or poison if desired—is a common house rule.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan that is a strict reading that can break the entire magic chapter of the CRB, as it is entirely written talking about spells. *raw* only spells would require line of sight, or have cone effects, or even follow the saving throw rules. Example: *A line of effect is a straight, unblocked path that **indicates what a spell can affect**. A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier. It’s like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that it’s not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight.*

Comment: I'm sorry but how? I mean, the example provided even says, "It’s like line of sight for ranged weapons." And spell-like abilities and supernatural abilities are already covered as being *like spells except.* Is there another example you can cite? Or is this a deliberately extreme reaction, like, "Well, it's an extraordinary cone attack and only the magic chapter covers cones, so I guess the GM makes up how extraordinary cones work." That sort of thing?

Comment: That line is describing how line of effects for *spells* work, but there are not rules describing how line of effects for extraordinary abilities work, or a text saying that they work like line of effects for weapons. So, how would they work if not work like *spells*?

Comment: I apologize. I came at this from the wrong angle. Let me start over: There's a [general description of how saving throws work in the Combat chapter](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Saving-Throws). Wouldn't this more specific description of saving throws—including voluntarily foegoing them—in the [Magic chapter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) apply to saving throws against magic?

Comment: [Mr James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1349?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#67430) can probably explain it better than I did. And though im looking for a proper quote from the devs saying that ["spells" in the magical chapter is merely refering to abilities in general](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q30u?What-can-be-done-through-a-Force-Effect#30), I could not find one. So its one of those things that will easily suffer table variation.

Comment: Paizo site has been wonky for the past few days, but Sean K. Reynolds confirmed back in 2012 that you still make a save against a poison effect even if you willingly try to fail the check ([link](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2npb2?Can-a-player-willingly-fail-a-saving-throw#15)). So I guess we have material to disallow voluntarily failing a fortitude save against an extraordinary effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are immune to the stench ability if one of the following is true:

- You have the stench ability
- You are immune to poison
- You have saved against the ability in the last 24 hours
- You are not a living creature

Additionally, you are *effectively* immune to the golem's stench ability if you are immune to the nauseated condition.

Note that removing your sense of smell and/or the golem's odor will *not* render you immune to the effects of the ability; the stench universal ability is, oddly, not dependent upon the ability to produce or process smell to have an effect (though the *negate aroma* spell would work, if it could affect the golem).  This is probably an oversight, though, as is the statement in the Universal Monster Rules text that the creature secretes an offensive oil.

The easiest of the above options to achieve is having saved in the last 24 hours.  That requires no resources and can be done by anyone with two minutes of time in which to take 20.

Beyond that, a *Gambodge Nodule Ioun Stone* can give you immunity to poison without taking up a slot for 54K gp, or immunity to just this one poison effect for 1.5k gp, or immunity to poison but also you're going to be diseased periodically if you stick around the golem for 40k gp.  A *periapt of proof against poison* takes your neck slot and costs 27k gp.  There are also a plethora of class options that grant immunity to poison.

There are very, very few ways to gain the stench ability.  Trogdolytes have it for free and are a playable race (and reincarnatable).  Other than that, you are limited only to the Ghoulish Aspect 20th level bloodline power of the Ghoul Bloodline Sorcerer, which seems unlikely to be helpful here, and *maybe* the Stench of the Grave manifestation of the Ghoul corruption.  The Ghoul corruption seems like a very useful resource in a party with a carrion golem, if its stench abilities count as stench, but it will require careful management to avoid insta-perma-death via 3rd stage corruption.  If going the route, consider also the *ring of the Troglodyte* (and maybe *putrid* armor, either defensively or offensively depending on the interpretation of its immunity stripping clause).

Not being a living creature means being undead or a construct.  These are already desirable things, but they are also difficult to achieve.

Immunity to nausea is quite helpful, but is gained in permanent form solely from class abilities, like the 8th level barbarian rage power Internal Fortitude or the 9th level ability of the 3rd level pestilence sorcerer bloodline power Accustomed to Awfulness.